# Android (Kotlin) cannot access child of TableRow element

Tags: android, kotlin, android-tablelayout, tablerow

I have a TableLayout that I build up programmatically, which works fine. However I cant access the children of the TableRow elements. row.getChildAt(x) results in "Unresolved Reference"

It looks to me from the log output that row is in fact of type TableRow, so I'm not sure why this fails. I'm new to Kotlin and Android so I'm looking for a bit of help.

My question is why is row.getChildAt available when creating the TableView, but not available later on when iterating through the TableView?

```
package com.example.daedalus.myapplication

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.TableRow
import android.widget.TextView
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_test_table.*

class testTable : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_table)
    val number = 5

    for(i in 0 until number) {
        val row = TableRow(this)
        val cell1 = TextView(this)
        cell1.text = "Hello"
        val cell2 = TextView(this)
        cell2.text = "Friend"
        row.addView(cell1)
        row.addView(cell2)
        tableLayout.addView(row)
        // row.getChildAt(x) works here
    }
    val view = Button(this)
    view.text = "Test"
    view.setOnClickListener(){
        for(i in 0 until tableLayout.childCount) {
            val row = tableLayout.getChildAt(i)
            //row.getChildAt(x) doesnt work here. Unresolved reference
            Log.i("MyApp",row.toString())
        }
    }
    linearLayout.addView(view)
   }
}
```

XML:

```
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

</TableLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="84dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tableLayout"></LinearLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Logcat Output

```
09-11 14:08:09.823 26050-26050/com.example.daedalus.myapplication I/MyApp: android.widget.TableRow{afec180 V.E...... ........ 0,0-954,51}
android.widget.TableRow{66d93b9 V.E...... ........ 0,51-954,102}
android.widget.TableRow{9c073fe V.E...... ........ 0,102-954,153}
android.widget.TableRow{ebcf75f V.E...... ........ 0,153-954,204}
09-11 14:08:09.824 26050-26050/com.example.daedalus.myapplication I/MyApp: android.widget.TableRow{c4e75ac V.E...... ........ 0,204-954,255}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `getChildAt(int)` is a method declared by ViewGroup, which TableLayout extends. If you have type hints enabled, you should see that `row` is just a `View` object.

Since TableLayout's children should all be TableRow objects, just cast:

```
val row = tableLayout.getChildAt(i) as TableRow
val item = row.getChildAt(whatever) //you may need to cast again
```

Comment: Thank you. That clarifies some other things I was having trouble with.